# Emacs skips every other line in LaTeX mode

Tags: latex

Is emacs supposed to skip every other line when it edits in LaTeX mode? It does so for me.

If so, how do I turn that off?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment, I'm creating an answer.

The answer to your first question is obviously: no.

Please post the relevant part of your emacs config to get help on the second question. What do you mean by "skip every other line"? Can't you place the cursor on every other line?

Comment: Basically, when I hit the enter key, emacs skips a line when editing in tex-mode. 
I found that this is caused by this in my .emacs:
`(define-key function-key-map [return] [?\C-j])`
However, I use this in other modes when I need to autotab while editing. How can I prevent this in Tex-Mode?